# Write line from 1 text file to a new text file, excluding the first 18 characters

Tags: batch-file, text, copy, output

I've searched many places and can't seem to come up with a solution to my problem.  I have a .bat file that contains the following line:

rasdial "TEST VPN" username password

I would like to copy only the username and password to a new text file so it would just have:

username password

Everything I've found during my search does the exact opposite, leaving me with:

rasdial "TEST VPN"

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm pretty sure this is easy, but I'm unable to figure it out on my own.

Thanks in advance!

Here's what I currently have:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "ln1="

>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\credentials.txt" (
    for /f "useback delims=" %%A in ("%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Project Resources Group\PRG Connect\AutoKeepVPNAlive.bat") do (
      if defined ln1 (
        set "ln2=%%A"
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!ln1!
        endlocal
        set "ln1="
      )
      for /f %%B in ("%%A") do if "%%B"=="rasdial" set "ln1=%%A"~18%
    )
  )
```

Contents of AutoKeepAliveVPN.bat are:

```
TITLE TEST Connect
@ECHO OFF

:loop
cls
set ip3=10.12.0.254
ping -n 1 %ip3% | find "Reply from %ip3%: bytes="
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    goto loop2
) else (
    goto connect
)

:loop2
cls
timeout 30
set ip1=google.com
ping -n 1 %ip1% | find "Lost = 0"
if not %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    goto loop2
) else (
    goto loop
)

:connect
cls
rasdial "TEST VPN" username password
if %ERRORLEVEL%==623 (
    goto setup
) else (
    net use P: "\\10.12.0.254\share"
    goto loop
)

:setup
cls
CALL "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Project Resources Group\PRG Connect\VPN Setup.bat"
exit
```

Comment: If you have a variable with that string assigned to it it is a simple sub string. `echo %var:~18%`

Comment: Please post the contents of **AutoKeepVPNAlive.bat**.

Comment: This is for a program I've created to keep users connected to my vpn server.  When I make changes to the program, I want users to be notified (which I have working) and have the option to update to the newest version.  Right now, I'm working on the last part that will keep them from having to run the setup again to enter credentials after the reinstallation finishes.  I'm basically trying to save their credentials to a temporary file so that I can copy them back into the new file once it's created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a much simpler way to do what you need to do.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('findstr /B /I /C:"rasdial" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Project Resources Group\PRG Connect\AutoKeepVPNAlive.bat"') do SET var=%%G
(echo %var:~18%)>>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\credentials.txt"
```

Comment: And that's why I asked.  I knew it had to be somewhat simple.  Thank you so much, Squashman!!!

Comment: @DDietz, you are welcome.  But next time try to provide as much information as possible in your initial question.  Otherwise people feel like a Dentist trying to pull a tooth.

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar!  Will do.  I just fear that I complicate things sometimes (most of the time) and don't want to confuse people that actually know what they're talking about.